# Making sure user can only access his own data on Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to ask you if my setup is enough secure to make sure the user can only access his own data on Firebase Realtime Database.

Or is there anything else I could add to make it more secure?

In my database every user has an account entry which is the string of an ethereum wallet account instead of his auth.uid.

The structure of the database looks like this:

```
{
  "accounts": {
    "account1": {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": "value"
    },
    "account2": {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": "value"
    },
    "account3": {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

After some testing it seems following security rules are only allowing access to the account data if the user knows his account string:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false,
        "accounts": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": false,
            "$account": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can only read the account data with the following example on line 3:

```
get(child(dbRef, `/`)).then((snapshot) => { // Not allowed
get(child(dbRef, `accounts/`)).then((snapshot) => { // Not allowed
get(child(dbRef, `accounts/${account}`)).then((snapshot) => { // Allowed
```

Comment: *I can only read the account data with the following example on line 3* so isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes its exactly what I want. But I am not sure if I missed anything. I want to make absolutely sure nobody can read outside of his own account.

Comment: If the reads that are made outside the user's own account are rejected by the security rules, then the rules are just fine, right?

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure nobody can get the list of all accounts. And nobody can read any account content without knowing the account string (ethereum wallet account string).

Comment: Have you tried to read the data outside the account and gain access? Can you show us a concrete example?

Comment: I have tested to read outside the account with ```get(child(dbRef, `/`)).then((snapshot) => {```and ```get(child(dbRef, `accounts/`)).then((snapshot) => {```. Both receive permission denied.

Comment: That sounds good to me, it means that the Firebase servers reject such operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules allow a user to read `/accounts/$account` for any value of `$account` that they know. There is nothing in your rules that ensures this is their own data, so it seems like your rules don't match your requirement.

To make the rules match, you should have some value in the data that identifies the "own data" and then check that value in your rules.

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation on [common security setups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#data-defined_attributes_and_roles) handy while writing these rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank. In my case accounts in the database are ethereum wallet accounts which I manually add to the database to whitelist them. This wallet account addresses are nearly impossible to guess. Then when a user is logged in with one of this addresses in his ethereum browser extension he get access only to data in the database under his logged in ethereum wallet account. He would have to guess the exact address to read data of another address entry.

Comment: It's usually not a matter of guessing an ID, but of intercepting it somewhere and then reusing it. Your rules are not secure against that.

Comment: Thank you Frank. At the moment I have no idea how I can improve my system. I only know that I will have the wallet accounts before the users access the page. So I have to whitelist them somehow. One more thing: This whitelisted accounts will only have access to the website for a limited amount of time. I will remove the accounts from the database after the user is done with the task on the website.

Comment: Your question was whether the rules you have implement your requirement of only allowing a user to enter their own data. I answered why it doesn't, what the risk is (data interception), and what steps you can take to implement the requirement (using auth, associating the data with a user, then enforcing it in the rules).